# Paypal go live link load infinite

Tags: paypal

I want to go live from my paypal account,  I need to provide information to go live, but the paypal link give me, didn't load.

This is the paypal [link](https://registration.paypal.com/welcomePage.do?bundleCode=C3&country=CA&partner=PayPalCA).

Comment: Where is that link from? Try without a bundle, https://registration.paypal.com/welcomePage.do?country=CA&partner=PayPalCA

Comment: Thank's it work now ! This link come from paypal developper from this : https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications